# Can org tables cooperate with my customized dates?

Tags: org-mode

I have my time stamps customized as follows

```
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%a %d-%b %Y>" . "<%a %d-%b %Y %H:%M>"))
```

My issue is that my org-tables do not align correctly when dates are inserted in them

```
| <2016-01-12 Tue>   | <2016-01-13 Wed>  |
|-------------------+-------------------|
| aligned           | improperly        |
```

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a one of a few [documented side effects](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html) of having your custom time stamps overlaid on top of the default time stamps. From the documentaion:

> If the custom timestamp format is longer than the default and you are using 
>    dates in tables, table alignment will be messed up. If the custom format is 
>    shorter, things do work as expected.

You could try to shorten your custom format, but other than that, you are probably out of luck. Also, note that the dates in your example table do not match your custom format. If you hand typed these dates, note that you can add a timestamp automatically in an org-mode buffer with `C-.` (`org-time-stamp`).

Comment: Whoops, they must have reverted when I pasted from my example doc. Thanks for the answer.