# How to set my own date format for Org

Tags: org-mode

Hello I am new to Emacs and I have started using org mode for improving my productivity.

Currently when I press `C-c .` the date format displayed is `<2016-01-26 Thu>` I would like to change it to `<Thu Jan 26th 2016>`

How do I make the corresponding changes in my `.emacs`?

Comment: Check out `C-h v org-time-stamp-formats` and `C-h f format-time-string`. AFAIK, there isn't a built-in way to suffix the likes of `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th` after the dates. Without those suffixes, the answer is easy. **Update**: Well, looks like there [**is** a way to add those ordinal suffixes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20317537/1219634).

Comment: Actually  `org-display-custom-times` and `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` might be the variables designed for user to tweak.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```el
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%a %b %e %Y>" . "<%a %b %e %Y %H:%M>"))
```

This will give you `<Thu Jan 26 2016>` for date timestamps or `<Thu Jan 26 2016 11:30>` for timestamps with times. If you want zero-padded dates instead of blank-padded dates use `%d` instead of `%e` above (e.g., if you want `09` instead of `9`, but I figured blank-padded would be better if you figure out a way to add the ordinal suffix). For a comprehensive list of the formatting symbols, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html). You can try to combine this with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317537/3642398) as suggested by @KaushalModi, but I haven't gotten that to work yet.

Also, if you use custom timestamps in org-mode, be aware that there are sometimes undesired side-effects: see [this question and answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/can-org-tables-cooperate-with-my-customized-dates/19492#19492) and [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html) from the org manual.

Comment: @KaushalModi, thanks for the highlighting! I wasn't sure how to do that!

Comment: You are welcome! Just for reference for anyone else, put `<!-- language: lang-el -->` followed by a blank line at the top of a code block. If you have only elisp code blocks but many of them, you can put just one `<!-- language-all: lang-el -->` at the top of the post.